# How to use subclass parameters in superclass method?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a superclass called `Player`, and I have 3 subclasses that are `Young Hustler`, `Student` and `The Herbalist`.

In every subclass I have private parameters `money`, `stashSize` and `connections`.

And I want to create a method in `Player` class called `sellWeed()` which removes 1 from `stashSize` and adds 10 to `money`, so that I could apply that method to all of the subclasses when calling them in the main method. But how do I get the private parameters from subclasses into the superclass?

I can't declare them in superclass because each subclass has it's own default starting parameters which should progress during the game.

Comment: edit question and write the code of those classes here.

Comment: move your parameters to the subclass and set the default values during initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
class Player {
  protected int money;
  protected int stashSize;
  // and the connections parameter too...
  public Player(int money, int stashSize) {
    this.money = money;
    this.stashSize = stashSize;
  }
  public void sellWeed() {
    // work with money and stashSize here
  }
}

class Student extends Player {
  public Student() {
    super(0, 10); // no money and stashSize 10 for student
  }
}
```

The idea is to move the private parameters to the super class. Then you can initialize them by passing the values to the super constructor (super()).